# Repercussions from continued noise

Tags: discussion, noise-reduction

I'm curious as to what levels moderators are tolerant of noise on the sites, understanding that those levels might be different across the sites.  We don't get all that much noise on SF as, seemingly, over on SO and certainly not the level as here on meta.

Blatantly offensive posts are one thing but continued, recurring noise can be quite a bit more subjective.  It's more blatantly identified by the community here on meta with the new **noise or pointless** close reason, and on the others as **off topic** or **subjective**.

Do diamond mods have filters or other tools available to them to be able to review questions closed by user / close reason?  If a user has a repeated pattern of posts closed as noise does that raise them as a candidate for the bin?  What would that threshold be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more noise on SO, but there are also a *lot* more 10K moderators.  As you noted, what constitutes "noise" is rather subjective, so I like to let the 10K mods do as much of the noise filtering as possible.  I'll delete it if it's pointed out to me, or if I happen to see it on my own, but I don't go looking for it.

We don't have any extra tools above the 10K tools for listing recently closed and deleted questions, so no filtering on close reason or user.  We can add annotations to a user's profile, so if someone's behavior is bad enough for enough repetitions it will raise some flags. (Although annotations are normally reserved for extremely bad (or good) behavior. (Nested parens!))

Comment: Thanks, Bill, that's great info.  I assume you'll let us know when we're pestering you too much with the flags :)

Comment: @squillman: No, I'll just start deleting them. ;)

Comment: Hah, fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

Flag for moderator attention. It seems to work wonders.